# Null-coalescing operator in conjuction with JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

I have below code written to read JArray from a given JObject.

To my understanding, when the value of "tags" in JObject is null, IEnumerable should be initialized as empty.

```
IEnumerable<string> tags = eventPayload?["tags"]?.Values<string>() ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

However, this lines throws exception when json looks like

```
{
    "tags": null   
}

System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.
```

If I were to make above line read null and initialize enumerable as empty, what changes do I need to make?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `eventPayload?["tags"]` is `JValue.Null`, not `null`.

Comment: Is there way to use JValue.Null with Null-coalescing operator??